# Two Rows value comparison in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

In my SQL Server table, I'm getting 'closed' status twice. I want to remove the second record.

To remove the second record condition should as below.

> IF First line END_TIME equal to Second-line START_TIME then the second Line should be removed. should only Pick the First Line

Please help me to solve this issue.

Refer to the attached screenshot

[image]

Comment: Look up "SQL MIN". That might be a good place to start and see if it solves your issue.

Comment: (Consumable) Sample data, and expected results will help us help you.

Comment: Edit your question and show (as text) the query used to generate this result set.

Comment: Actually, this record getting from the table. Because of the system record duplication. If the first line END_TIME equal to Second line START_TIME then should only pick the first record

Comment: I suggest you improve your question,especially try to don’t add a picture, Have a look here => [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can use a delete based on a join, where you join the table to itself, on columns end_time and start_time.

```
DELETE t2
FROM MyTable t1
INNER JOIN MyTable t2 on t1.END_TIME = t2.END_TIME
WHERE t1.STATUS = 'Closed'
AND t2.STATUS = 'Closed'
```

This would delete the record with STATUS = 'Closed' that had a start time that is the same as the closing time of another record. If I understand your scenario correctly, this is what would do the trick. But you would need to elaborate on your exact scenario. And maybe add a transaction that only commits if a single record is affected, because a record with a start time and another record with the same end time might not always be related.

Comment: Thanks a lot got the answer

Answer (score 0):

Here a full example, including table creation and row insertion and deletion.
I also considered the case when start_time is equal to the end_time.

```
create table [TABLE] (start_time int, status varchar(max), end_time int);
GO -- create the table
insert into [TABLE] values (1,'CLOSED', 2),(2,'CLOSED', 3);
GO -- insert two rows 1st end is 2nd start
delete from [TABLE] where status='CLOSED' and start_time in (select end_time from  [TABLE] where status='CLOSED' and start_time<>end_time) 
GO -- will delete the 2nd row
select * from [TABLE] 
GO -- show cleaned table
```